# Помогите с игрой на Си

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)

{

char ansver[4] ;

char action ;

char participant ;

char place ; 

char end ;


    printf ("Это детская игра \n \"Чепуха\"");

    printf ("хотите сыграть?");

   scanf (" %s " , ansver); 

   if  (ansver == yes); 

   printf ("действие");
   scanf (" %s " , &action);

   printf ("участник действия");
   scanf (" %s " , &participant);

   printf ("место действия");
   scanf (" %s " , place);

   printf ("чем это все закончилось?");
   scanf (" %s " , &end); 

   printf ("вот что у вас получается: \n");
   printf (" %s на %s %s %s " , participant , place , action , end);


   if (ansver == no);
   return 0;

   return 0;

   }
```

Comment: А в чём состоит вопрос? Какого рода помощь требуется? Угадать, что у вас за игра и какую логику вы хотели реализовать, но не реализовали, понять ваш код, найти в нём ошибки и исправить?

Comment: А чем помочь то ? сходу могу только заметить что после `if (ansver == yes);` стоит точка с запятой и никакие действия не производит

Comment: Исправить ошибки что бы игра работала

Comment: Работала как ? Что она должна делать. Тут как бы особых ошибок нет, кроме точек с запятой после if, которые ничего не делают. Просто программа что то спрашивает и что то сообщает более ничего не пытаясь делать, но возможно это и требовалось ?

Comment: Код очень лёгкий ведь я только начинаю изучать си а смысл этого кода что он по порядку спрашивает : место, действие , персонажа и концовку и просто соединяет это воедино это такая глупая детская игра но компелятор упорно не хочет компелировать мой код ссылаясь на то что я не правельно работаю с операторами if и мол он говорит чувак это работает совсем не так исправь или я не смогу это скомпенсировать...

Comment: @user Вот, эти вот ошибки, которые выводил компилятор и надо было привести в тексте вопроса. Тут почти нет ясновидцев и предсказать чисто в уме какая строка какие ошибки породит на используемом Вами компиляторе мы не можем. Зато если бы был текст ошибок, могли бы их растолковать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ладно, попробую угадать ответ, пока вопрос не закрыли.

Что сразу бросается в глаза (не считая точку с запятой после if'а, о которой сказали в комментариях): вы пытаетесь прочитать строку в переменную типа `char`, а не `char[]`. Нужно динамически выделать память под строковые переменные с помощью `malloc`. Также что вообще должен значсить этот код `(ansver == yes)`? Вы где-то определили переменную `yes`? И даже если да, то так строки не сравниваются, для этого нужно пользоваться `strcmp`. Вообще почитайте любую книгу по С, особенно главу по работу с памятью и строками, и большая часть проблем с вашим кодом станет понятна. Просто доведенный до ума ваш код может выглядеть так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STRING 20
int main (void)
{
    char ansver[4] ;
    char * action = malloc(MAX_STRING * sizeof(char));
    char * participant = malloc(MAX_STRING * sizeof(char));
    char * place = malloc(MAX_STRING * sizeof(char)); 
    char * end = malloc(MAX_STRING * sizeof(char));
    printf ("Это детская игра \n \"Чепуха\"");
    printf ("хотите сыграть?");
    scanf (" %s " , ansver); 

    if (strcmp(ansver, "yes") == 0) { 
        printf ("действие");
        scanf (" %s " , action);
        printf ("участник действия");
        scanf (" %s " , participant);
        printf ("место действия");
        scanf (" %s " , place); // здесь тоже надо передвать адрес
        printf ("чем это все закончилось?");
        scanf (" %s " , end); 
        printf ("вот что у вас получается: \n");
        printf (" %s на %s %s %s " , participant , place , action , end);
    } 
    //if (ansver == no); вот это вообще не надо, код и так завершится если ansVer не будет равен "yes"
    //return 0;

    return 0;
}
```